# how to set logger objecte to any module controller in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

how to configure and use logger in ZEND-framework 2 ?
is it good way to create logger object in application bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2):

First you can setup your Service Manager Config:

```
'factories' => array(
    'Zend\Log\Logger' => function($sm){
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger;
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('./data/log/'.date('Y-m-d').'-error.log');
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        return $logger;
    },
)
```

then in your controller you can add something like this

```
/**
 * Get the logger
 * 
 * @return  \Zend\Log\Logger
 */
protected function _getLog()
{
    if($this->_log == NULL) {
        $this->_log = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Log\Logger');
    }

    return $this->_log;
}

/**
 * Shortcut for logging method. 
 * Swapped parameter order to save code inside controllers.
 *
 * @param  mixed $message
 * @param  int $priority
 * @param  array|Traversable $extra
 * @return Logger
 * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException if message can't be cast to string
 * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException if extra can't be iterated over
 * @throws Exception\RuntimeException if no log writer specified
 */
protected function _log($message, $priority = \Zend\Log\Logger::DEBUG, $extra = array())
{
    return $this->_getLog()->log($priority, $message, $extra);
}
```

Notice the order of the parameters was swapped, just to cut down on code in the controller, makes things a little simpler.

Then you have a shortcut if you want to log anything in your controller:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $this->_log('Testing');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Rob Allen's blog on [logging exceptions](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/simple-logging-of-zf2-exceptions/). He shows how to use a `ServiceManager` factory in one module to instantiate the logger and writers. You can then call the logger through the `ServiceManager` from any other class that has access to it, such as controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Since Zend Framework 2.2, just set these lines in your config:

```
'log' => array(
    'Application\Log' => array(
        'writers' => array(
            array(
                'name'     => 'stream',
                'priority' => 1000,
                'options'  => array(
                    'stream' => 'data/logs/app.log',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Use it in your application controller:

```
 protected $log;

 public function getLog()
 {
     if (!$this->log) {     
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->log = $sm->get('Application\Log');
     }
     return $this->log;
 }
```

Read more - [zf2.2 release notes](http://framework.zend.com/blog/zend-framework-2-2-0-stable-released.html)